# When someones does everything he is asked to do (expression)

Tags: idioms, expressions

Is there an expression to use when someone does not do something or does something, because, for example, he does not want to offend that person or upset him.

For example, your close friend asks you to do something. You don't really want to do it, but you do it, because you think if you don't, he will get upset.

Is there any expression defining the act?
Or is there one that describes the type of relationship between you and your friend? Describing a relationship in which one side finds it really hard to refuse the other's request fearing he might get upset.

> A: She asked you to do her homework and you did it again?!
>     B: Well,
>   yes. I didn't want to upset her. (Something that B can say about himself and the way their relationship is)

I'm not sure if saying the person is "constrained by reserve" can fit the context. Cause might sound weird if B says "I'm usually constrained by feelings of reserve in my friendship with her."

Comment: A relationship in which one side finds it really hard to refuse the other's request fearing he might get upset, is called **abusive**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Vane Yeah, but I wondered if there is an expression that doesn't have a very negative connotation!

Comment: I answered the second of your two questions. Positively, the first *could* be **tactful**, but I would say **submissive**. It might depend on the local culture.

Comment: How about the word "humor" as a verb: "to do what someone wants or to pretend to agree with them so that they do not become upset" https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/humour.

Comment: The question edit reinforces what I said: your "friend" wants you to do their homework. The simple answer is "do your own homework". That will test how much of a "friend". Getting upset, is the weapon that your abuser uses to threaten you.

Comment: Possibly **bite the bullet**, which is to say - doing something just to get it over with, most often when it's assumed that the *something* in question will need to be performed anyway. And then, perhaps **..wears the pants in the relationship..** can be used to describe the relationship between the two people, with the person who wears the pants being the dominant figure.

Comment: Another expression to describe the relationship is **all give and no take**, with Person B always giving.

Comment: You might say that someone decided to **go along to get along**, that is, to quietly comply with what is expected of them in order not to cause trouble or stand out.

Answer (score 2):

**From her side:** *exploit, take advantage of, abuse, use, manipulate, milk, misuse, dump on, play on or upon.*

**From his side:** *oblige, humor, indulge, cater (to), gratify, cocker, coddle, cosset, mollycoddle, pamper, spoil.*

Answer (score 1):

How about the word "humor" as a verb. The definition in [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/humour) is:

> to do what someone wants or to pretend to agree with them so that they
>   do not become upset

Comment: See question edit, it is about doing someone else's homework.

Comment: Apparently there is a relationship based on parasitism. We need to find a word  that can be used for the act of the counter part of a parasite in social environments.